# I keep getting expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'void' void createCell(struct cell myCell, int type, int immutable)

Tags: c, linux

So, I keep getting the compiler to tell me that there's an error before my first function declaration. Before this, I had defined an enum (before my first function), and then it was telling me the same error but right before the enum declaration.

> error: "expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'void'  void
>   createCell(struct cell myCell, int type, int immutable)"

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "dungeon.h"
 #define true 1
 #define false 0
 #define max_x 20
 #define max_y 79


//why does it expect an identifier here?//
void createCell(struct cell myCell, int type, int immutable)
{
  if(type == 0)
    myCell.type = " ";

  if(type == 1)
    myCell.type = "#";

  if(type == 2)
    myCell.type = ".";

  myCell.immutable = immutable;
}


void border_generator(struct cell cells[21][80]) {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 80; j++) {


      if (i == 0 || i == max_x)
    {
      createCell(cells[i][j], 0, true);
      printf("-");
    }

      else if( i > 0  && (j == 0 || j == max_y))
    {
      createCell(cells[i][j], 0, true);
      printf("|");
    }
      else {
    createCell(cells[i][j], 0, false);
    printf("%c", cells[i][j].type);
      }
      if (j == max_y){
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  } 

}


void room_generator()
{


}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct cell cells[21][80];
  border_generator(cells);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats in `dungeon.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a struct or union definition not terminated by a semicolon (';') at the end of "dungeon.h".

It's easy to reproduce the very same error:

```
$ cat | cc -x c -
# 0 "dungeon.h"
struct foo { int x; }
# 3 "main.c"
void createCell(void){}
^D
main.c:3:1: error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to C, sorry.